# Problems with audio playback using arduino

Tags: python, arduino, audio-recording, microphone

I am trying to create a system a part of which requires a microphone to be connected to an arduino. I haven't worked with microphones a lot.

I have connected a microphone ([Adafruit Electret Microphone Amplifier - MAX9814 with Auto Gain Control](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00SLYAI9K) ) to an arduino nano. I want to record audio data from this.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    Serial.println(analogRead(A2));
    }
}
```

I send the data to the computer and record it using a python script and converted it into a WAV file to make sure that the microphone is working properly. I tried multiple things, using the ADC value, scaling the ADC value between -1 and 1, converting into voltage and then scaling it, but nothing seems to work. When I play it back all I can hear is static with a few clicks where the voice should be.

Below is the python code i wrote for the configuration where I am sending the ADC value using println. Here I collect the data using pyserial library and convert it into a float. Then I normalize it between -1 and 1. Then I save it in a wav file.

```
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

import pyaudio
import wave

def audnorm(aud):
    normaud=  -1+2*((aud-np.amin(aud))/(np.amax(aud)-np.amin(aud)))
    return normaud

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200)
ser.flushInput()

sound=[]
sound2=[]

while True:
    try:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        ser_bytes2= float(ser_bytes)
        sound.append(ser_bytes2)
        sound2.append(ser_bytes)
        print(ser_bytes+"\t"+str(ser_bytes2))
        print(type(ser_bytes))
    except:
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")
        break
print(str(len(sound)))

soundnp= np.asarray(sound)

soundnp= soundnp - np.mean(soundnp)


soundnorm= audnorm(soundnp)

soundnormstr= [str(x) for x in soundnorm]

plt.plot(soundnp)
plt.show()

plt.plot(soundnorm)
plt.show()


wf = wave.open("output.wav", 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(1)
wf.setsampwidth(2)
wf.setframerate(10000)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(soundnormstr))
wf.close()
```

I have attached 2 images of the data I recorded using this code.

What am I doing wrong?

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFzWB.png)
[Normalized Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEGjH.png)

Comment: Serial.available() is true when there is input available to be read by the Arduino. Because you are not sending data to the Arduino, you can remove the if (Serial.available()) statement.

Answer (score 0):

To be recorded without distortion, the signal you're trying to record - I assume it's an audio signal - requires three things: 1) sampling at a uniform rate, 2) sampling at more than 8,000 samples per second to be able to barely understand a voice, and 3) transmitting or storing the data as fast as you acquire it.

re: 1 & 2) There is an instructable that goes into all the messy details of recording high-fidelity audio on the Arduino. It contains far more information than I could write here. See https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Audio-Input/

If your application requires the Arduino to simply detect that there is a sound - such as a clapping pair of hands - you can get by with a lower and non-uniform sample rate. Search for "Arduino Clapper" to get some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bradford. You will need to make a uniform sampling to acquire the audio signal and 8000 Hz is a minimum.

I think that you need to set a higher serial baud rate to achieve this sampling frequency. I have slightly modified your code to measure with an oscilloscope the "actual maximum frequency" of the serial "transmission" (plus the analogWrite).

```
void setup() {
  // Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  //if(Serial.available())
  {
    int val = analogRead(A2);
    Serial.write(0);
    }

}
```

On the oscilloscope, it is roughly 9 kHz frequency, sending simply zeros on the serial wire. see the attached [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiQQK.png). It might be doable (for speech, not for music).